# Wicket Header Render Strategy

Tags: java, wicket

I am using Wicket 1.5.x with `<wicket:head>` tag. I tried rendering the child component (Wicket Panel) CSS / JS 1st then followed by the parent. It didn't work. It always renders the parent (Wicket WebPage) JS 1st. I used **`-DWicket_HeaderRenderStrategy=org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy`** or **`ParentFirstHeaderRenderStrategy`** and it rendered the same HTML output. Do these header renderers strategy works with `<wicket:head>` tag at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4000

Answer (score 0):

For pages the header fragments of the markup are always taking first while wicket constructs the basic page markup.

If you want to add the head fragment of the page last you would have to override the renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) method.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.renderCSSReference("mycss.css");
}
```

This one will use the choosen *IHeaderRenderStrategy*

Comment: Thanks. That an alternative. However, it still doesn't answer my question. How do I arrange JS / CSS links in my <wicket:head>?

Comment: If you're declaring <wicket:head> in a Page markup you aren't able to add anything from a Panel before that. You would have to declare everything with renderHead(), even in your pages.

Comment: Apparently it could be a bug 

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Does-Parent-Child-HeaderRenderStrategy-work-with-lt-wicket-head-gt-tag-td4075161.html